# TypeError: data.isbn is undefined

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, json

I was receiving the following error:

```
TypeError: data.isbn is undefined
```

I have since added in the `data.isbn ==null` statement in the following code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "getInventory.php",
    datatype: "json",
    data: ({skuStart: $("#startSkuRange").val(), skuEnd: $("#endSkuRange").val(),
        processDate: $("#processDate").val(), source: $("#source").val()}),
    success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    if (data.isbn == null) {
            $("#inventoryUpdate").append('<tr><td>No Records Found</td></tr>');
        } else {
            for(var x=0; x<data.isbn.length; x++) {
                $("#inventoryUpdate").append('<tr><td id="tableSKU">'+data.sku[x]+'</td><td id="tableISBN">'+data.isbn[x]+
                    '</td><td><input type="text" id="tableQuantity" value="'+data.quantity[x]+
                    '"/></td><td><input type="text" id="tableDefect" value="'+data.defect[x]+
                    '"/></td><td><input type="text" id="tableSource" value="'+data.source[x]+
                    '"/></td><td><input type="text" id="tableFeature" value="'+data.feature[x]+
                    '"/></td><td><input type="text  id="tableLocation" value="'+data.location[x]+
                    '"/></td><td><input type="text" id="tableProcessDate" value="'+date.processDate[x]+
                    '"/></td><td><input type="text" id="tableBookType" value="'+data.booktype[x]+
                    '"/></td><td><input type="text" id="tableCreatedBy" value="'+data.created[x]+
                    '"/></td><td><input type="text" id="tableModifiedBy" value="'+data.modified[x]+
                    '"/></td></tr>');
            }

            $("#inventoryUpdate").trigger("update");
        }
    }
});// end of ajax call
```

This now returns `No Records Found`, however, my *console.log(data)* is showing me that there are 19 isbn's.  Can anyone see where the error lies?  I am using identical code in another program and it works fine.

**EDIT**:  Here is the PHP file that it gets the info from:

```
if(!empty($start) && !empty($end)){
    $result = $conn->query("Select * from inventory where sku >= $start and sku <= $end");
} elseif (isset($start) && isset($end) && isset($source)){
    $result = $conn->query("Select * from inventory where sku >= '$start' and sku <= '$end' and source_id = '$source'");
} elseif (isset($processDate)) {
    $result = $conn->query("Select * from inventory where date_process = '$processDate'");
} else {
    $result = $conn->query("Select * from inventory where sku >= '$start' and sku <= '$end' or source_id = '$source' or date_process = '$processDate'");
}

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $skuArray[$x] = $row['sku'];
    $isbnArray[$x] = $row['isbn13'];
    $qtyArray[$x] = $row['quantity'];
    $defectArray[$x] = $row['defect_id'];
    $sourceArray[$x] = $row['source_id'];
    $featureArray[$x] = $row['feature_id'];
    $locationArray[$x] = $row['location_id'];
    $processDateArray[$x] = $row['date_process'];
    $bookTypeArray[$x] = $row['book_type_id'];
    $createdByArray[$x] = $row['created_by'];
    $modifiedByArray[$x] = $row['modified_by'];

    $x++;
} // end of while loop  

$results = array('sku' => $skuArray,
                 'isbn' =>$isbnArray,
                 'quantity' => $qtyArray,
                 'feature' => $featureArray,
                 'processDate' => $processDateArray,
                 'source' => $sourceArray,
                 'location' => $locationArray,
                 'created' => $createdByArray,
                 'modified' => $modifiedByArray,
                 'booktype' => $bookTypeArray,
                 'defect' => $defectArray,
                 );

$conn->close();
echo json_encode($results);
```

*console.log(data)* is:

```
{"sku":["10123400","10123401","10123402","10123403","10123404","10123405","10123406","10123407","10123408","10123409","10123410","10123411","10123412","10123413","10123414","10123415","10123416","10123417","10123418"],
 "isbn":["9781416025405","9780072993288","9780534380311","9780495095538","9780781778107","9780205741786","9780673985255","9780618331505","9780321106766","9780495506218","9780321557537","9780534629915","9780312664817","9780198610298","9780323046343","9780323023108","9781439036402","9780132497992","9780538497817"]}
```

This is one string, but i edited it for easier reading and it does return the rest of the information asked for, but it is a long string and I did not add it for brevity.

Comment: Can you show what  `console.log(data)` results in exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I feel like a compete MORON! I had `datatype: "json"`. It needs to be `dataType: "json"`.  The "T" in `dataType` needs to be capitalized. Everything works fine now.  Thanks to all who have tried to help me out. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Check *console.log* for `data.isbn` than you will be sure that the data is there and javascript `'TypeError: data.isbn is undefined'` is given when the variable is declared but not initialized. So it should be `if(typeof data.isbn == 'undefined')` and I guess `data.isbn` is `null` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can `use data.isbn`. It may have to be `data["isbn"]`, if in your back-end script you are using `json_encode(array(...))` assuming it is PHP.

Comment: I use data.isbn in many other programs and it works any other time.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is going to change anything, but maybe setting the PHP header to header('Content-type: application/json'); would help narrow down the possibilities?

Comment: Sorry MasterGberry, it did not help, I am still getting the same result.

Comment: Is only isbn not working?  Or none of them are?  If only isbn is not working then you may want to simply rename it to isbn2 or something...i've seen some strange things that a quick rename fixes.

Comment: I have been trying with isbn and with sku, and nothing is working.  I have the EXACT same lines of code earlier in the script, and that is working just fine

Comment: The same javascript? or PHP?  Are they under two different listner calls?  or the same one?

Comment: ajax call is in JS and the db query is PHP, the start and end are called from a PHP file.  All seems to work except the tablesorter table which needs the AJAX call to work correctly.

Comment: Well the fact that this can't be solved easily is frustrating...but why don't you just handle the HTML response in the PHP? So instead of doing it in the javascript you just provide a string of new rows that you can append in the HTML?  You would obviously have to change the datatype to HTML instead of json.  Since all you are doing is adding some rows to a table you don't really have to handle the actual formatting in the javascript.  See if this works :)

Comment: I will give that a try, and you are right, it is very frustrating especially since it works any other time I do the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Are you catching multiple objects within `data`?

I am assuming that your response looks like:

```
data
     isbn
         0
           sku
           price
         1 
           sku
           price
         ...
```

Is this the case?

Also, try accesing your `data` object as an array and see if it changes the results:

Use:

```
data['isbn']
```

Instead of

```
data.isbn
```

Comment: I am access multiple objects with data.  I just tried changing it to data['isbn'] and still get "No Records Found"

Answer (score 0):

I suggest changing this line of code:

```
if(data.isbn == null ){
```

to

```
if(data.isbn === null ){ // triple '=' sign
```

More information : [Comparison Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)

Comment: I just tried your suggestion, and I am still getting "No Records Found"